# javax.mail.Transport.send() causing a "java.awt.Component is a restricted class." when attaching a jpg

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

Here is the exception I get sometimes when trying to send mail with attachments on Appengine :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Component is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:375)
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:588)
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:542)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:617)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getInputStream(DataHandler.java:240)
    at javax.activation.DataHandlerDataSource.getInputStream(DataHandler.java:708)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:764)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:718)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:548)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:133)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:1393)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:1366)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:76)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
```

I use this code to send a mail :

```
Properties props = new Properties(); 
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession); 
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

// first part (the html) 
BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
htmlPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html"); 
multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart); 

// second part (the image) 
BodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
attachmentPart.setFileName("screenshot.jpg"); 
DataSource imageSrc = new ByteArrayDataSource(image, "image/jpeg"); 
attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(imageSrc)); 
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart); 

message.setContent(multipart); 
message.saveChanges(); 
Transport.send(message);
```

When this exception occurs on an instance, it becomes unstable and is no longer able to send emails with attachment. The only solution I found is to kill the instance and start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Is "image" really a byte array?

The stack trace suggests that you've set the attachment as an Image object, so JAF is trying to find a DataContentHandler to convert it to a byte array, and that DataContentHandler is using an AWT class that's not allowed.  There's no such DataCOntentHandler configured by default so I don't know where it's coming from.  Maybe GAE has a different configuration?

Also, what version of [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) are you using?